# Why this program is truncating output?

Tags: c

Am I doing anything wrong in this following program?

Code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
long x=1290323123123;
int len = snprintf(NULL,0, "%ld", x);

printf("%ld  %ld",x,len);

 return 0;
}
```

Output:
1832934323  10

Comment: works correctly on my machine

Comment: Did you get a warning error on the assignment about value truncation?

Comment: On machines with `long` smaller than 42 bits, this program has implementation-defined behavior due to conversion to a signed type that cannot hold the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1290323123123 requires 41 bits to store, but that `long` probably is just 32-bit long, so the extra 9 bits are gone.

```
1290323123123 = 0x12c6d405bb3
                  ^^^
                  excessive data that is chopped off

              =    0x6d405bb3

              = 1832934323
```

Use

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int64_t x = 1290323123123LL;
//  ^^^^^^^                  ^^
    int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%"PRId64, x);
//                                ^^^^^^^
    printf("%"PRId64" %d\n", x, len);
//           ^^^^^^^^
    return 0;
}
```

to make sure the type is at least 64-bit long, so it can store that value completely (result: http://www.ideone.com/BnTjJ).

Comment: It would be easier (although excessive on some machines) to just use `long long`, which is always at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'long' type can only hold 4 bytes.  The value you've assigned 'x' is greater than 4 bytes.

```
Hex(1290323123123) = 12C 6D40 5BB3
Hex(1832934323 ) = 6D40 5BB3
```

So the number it's outputting is the same as the lower 4 bytes of the number you're trying to print.

Some compilers may have larger 'long' types - prior to C99 and the introduction of types like `int64_t` I don't think there is one standard for (name, size) pairs.